# Deduction of "Disjunction elimination"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have at my disposal Modus Ponens (MP) and the three axioms:

- A1: $(\alpha\to(\beta\to\alpha))$,
- A2: $((\alpha\to(\beta \to\gamma))\to ((\alpha\to\beta)\to(\alpha\to\gamma)))$,
- A3: $(((\lnot\beta)\to(\lnot\alpha))\to(((\lnot\beta)\to\alpha)\to\beta))$.

I'm trying to prove the **Disjunction elimination**:
$$
\{\alpha\lor\beta,\alpha\to \gamma,\beta\to \gamma\}\vdash \gamma.
$$

$\lor$ is not part of the alphabet I use, the deduction actually is:
$$
\{((\neg\alpha)\to\beta),\alpha\to \gamma,\beta\to \gamma\}\vdash \gamma.
$$

The deduction should be something like

\begin{array}{rl|l}
\hline
1:&((\neg\alpha)\to\beta)  & Premiss\\ 
2:&\beta\to \gamma&Premiss\\
3:&((\neg\alpha)\to\gamma)&1,2\ H.S.\\
4:&(\alpha \to \gamma)&Premiss\\
5:&\gamma& 3,4 [?]\\
\hline
\end{array}

Where H.S. is *Hypothetical Syllogism*, a deduction that I have already proven.

> The rule $[?]$, that I have to prove, correspond to 
>   $$
> \{\alpha\to\beta,(\neg\alpha)\to\beta\}\vdash \beta.\tag{*}
> $$

(*) looks quite simple, but after hours no way to get it.

For information I have, if needed, proven other results, that I could reuse:

- $\vdash\alpha\to\alpha$,
- Hypothetical Syllogism: $\{\alpha\to\beta,\beta\to\gamma\}\vdash\alpha\to\gamma$,
- $\vdash(\lnot\alpha\to\alpha)\to\alpha$,
- $\vdash\alpha\lor\lnot\alpha$,
- $\{\alpha\to(\beta\to\gamma),\beta\}\vdash\alpha\to\gamma$,
- $\vdash(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$.
- Negation introduction:
  $\{(\alpha\to\beta),(\alpha\to \neg\beta)\}\vdash \neg \alpha$.
- Negation elimination:
  $\{\neg \alpha\}\vdash (\alpha\to \beta)$.
- Double negative elimination:
  $\neg \neg \alpha\vdash \alpha$.
- Conjunction introduction:
  $\{\alpha,\beta\}\vdash (\alpha\land \beta)$.

**EDIT** Additional known results:

- $\neg\neg\alpha\vdash\alpha$
- $\{\alpha,\neg\alpha\}\vdash\neg\beta$
- $\{\alpha,\neg\alpha\}\vdash\beta$
- Conjunction elimination, only $\alpha\land\beta\vdash\beta$
- Disjunction introduction, only $\beta\vdash\alpha\lor\beta$

Comment: It seems easier to me prove modus tollens, which will allow you to do contraposition, i.e. $\neg \alpha \rightarrow \gamma$ is the same as $\neg \gamma \rightarrow \alpha$. Then you do not need your rule $(*)$. Furthermore, modus tollens would probably help you prove $(*)$: If you know $\neg \beta \rightarrow \neg \alpha$ and $\neg \beta \rightarrow \alpha$, then $\neg \beta$ would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @mrp The proof of modus tollens would be also nice to have, sadly I wasn't able to derive it until now

Comment: @LiPo Ha!  I was in the middle or writing my answer, the first step was the derivation of Modus Tollens!  With that, so you're almost there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are allowed to use the Deduction Theorem:

Let's first prove Modus Tollens: $\varphi \rightarrow \psi, \neg \psi \vdash \neg \varphi$:

1. $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ Premise
2. $\neg \psi$ Premise
3. $\neg \psi \rightarrow (\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi)$ A1
4. $\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi$ MP 2,3
5. $\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ Double Negation Elimination
6. $\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi$ H.S. 1,5
7. $(\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi) \rightarrow ((\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \neg \varphi)$ A3
8. $(\neg \neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \neg \varphi$ MP 4,7
9. $\neg \varphi$ MP 6,8

With the Deduction Theorem, this gives us Contraposition: $\varphi \rightarrow \psi  \vdash \neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \varphi$

And now we can show $\varphi \rightarrow \psi, \neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi \vdash \psi$:

1. $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ Premise
2. $\neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi$ Premise
3. $\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \varphi$ Contraposition 1
4. $\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \neg \varphi$ Contraposition 2
5. $(\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \neg \varphi) \rightarrow ((\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \psi)$ A3
6. $(\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \varphi) \rightarrow \psi$ MP 4,5
7. $\psi$ MP 3,6

Comment: wow! thank you!

Comment: @LiPo You're welcome!  It's just a matter of creating a library of all these Lemma's. Creating them is a pain, but once you have them, proofs get easier and easier :)